# Two asynchronous events the second depending on the first

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, asynchronous, event-handling

I am creating some stuff on a `.on()` jquery handler like that

```
$('#idhere').on('click', function(){
   //create a couple of divs with a class
   });
```

Now I also want to add an event on the divs created, I have tried:

```
$('.divcreated').bind('mouseover', function(){
   //do some magic
   });
```

For some reason the second event is never triggered probably because they are both asynchronous. Any ideas to trigger the second event?

Comment: the second event never happens because the elements don't exist when you try to select them. Either bind the event when you create the elements, or use event delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already said, your new divs are not created when you try to register the mouseover event. So, you can try something like this for one div:

```
$('#idhere').on('click', function(){

   // creates the new div and assigns it to the $myNewDiv var
   var $myNewDiv = $( "<div></div>" );

   // register the event...
   $myNewDiv.on( "mouseover", function( event ) { ... }); 

   // add $myNewDiv to a container

});
```

I think that now you will be able to write your solution.

Comment: So the idea here is to group all the divs and give the event to the grouping div, isn't it? Also just nesting one event inside another makes the nested one able be triggered anytime?

Answer (score 1):

An element has to exist at the time of binding so you either have to bind it after you create the element or use delegation -

using delegation jQuery 1.7+

```
$('body').on('mouseover', '.divcreated', function(){
       //do some magic
});
```

That binds the event handler to the `body` - which exists at the time you are binding the events - which is on dom ready.  It is more efficient binding to a closer static parent element though.